# Replacing all colons with dashes in a set of files?

Tags: find, filenames, rename

I tried to replace all colons with dashes in filenames from files in some subfolders using the following command:

```
find . -type f -name "*:*" -exec rename -n 's/:/-/g' {} +
```

However I get an error saying

```
rename: not enough arguments
```

From googling around, it seems this is because I have a different version of rename than the one required for the command above. So how can I 'convert' this command to one that will work with my rename version?

My rename version is 'rename from util-linux 2.28.2'

Comment: Do you have a `prename` command instead for the `perl` variant of `rename` which that command line is expecting?

Comment: I don't have prename, I just checked.

Comment: Why don't you install the `rename` package?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there are two main unrelated and completely incompatible variants of a `rename` command on Linux systems.

A `perl` one (started as an example script decades ago, was shipped alongside `perl` for a verily  long time, and you find it nowadays as one or several separate packages with a few extensions). That one is called `rename` or sometimes `prename` on systems where `rename` is something else.

That's the one that command line is expecting.

And there's a very limited `rename` utility in `util-linux`. That one is sometimes called `rename.ul` on systems where `rename` is the `perl`'s `rename`.

With that one, you can only replace one occurrence of one string with another. You could do `-execdir rename : - {} +`, but that would only replace one colon (`12:30:00.log` -> `12-30:00.log`).

Here, you could implement `rename` by hand with:

```
find . -name '*:*' -type f -print0 | perl -0ne '
  rename $_, s{[^/]+$}{$& =~ y/:/-/r}res or warn "rename $_: $!"'
```

(here making sure the `:`s are replaced with `-` only in the basename of the files, as if directories contained `:`, that would fail).

Or using a shell instead of `perl` to do the substitution and call `mv` for the renaming (here using `bash` and the `${var//pattern/replacement}` ksh parameter expansion operator, you can replace `bash` with `ksh` or `zsh` if you don't have `bash`):

```
find . -name '*:*' -type f -exec bash -c '
  for file do
    base=${file##*/}
    mv "$file" "${file%/*}/${base//:/-}"
  done' bash {} +
```

Or use `zsh` and its `zmv` function:

```
autoload zmv
zmv '(**/)(*:*)(#qD.)' '$1${2//:/-}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Without `rename`:

```
find . -type f -name '*:*' -execdir bash -c 'echo mv "$1" "${1//:/-}"' bash {} \;
```

Try that as shown, then remove `echo` if you think it does the right thing.

This uses `-execdir` to execute `bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1//:/-}"'` with each found filename as an argument.  The inner shell created by `bash -c` will receive a name in `$1` and `${1//:/-}` will be expand to that name with all `:` replaced by `-`.

(The trailing `bash` towards the end in the command is what will be given to `$0` inside the `bash -c` subshell.)